# Get Data from 3rd party Applications Using Intent

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to get the string URL of a video form the Youtube Application share button. SO far I can retrieve the action and the type of the Intent which is sent from youtube to my app but I can't figure it out how to get the data.
The problem is when i try to get the Extras i need the key what youtube is sending in order to retrieve the string. Is there any way to retrieve the data?

```
        var myintent = Intent;
        string action = myintent.Action;
        string type = myintent.Type;
        string youtubeString = myintent.Extras.GetString("key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test sharing for the YouTube app, I got a Subject and Text where subject was a description of the video and Text was the URL. If you debug and break so you can inspect `bundle` you will see it contains something like the following:

```
{Bundle[{android.intent.extra.SUBJECT=Watch "Preview: Can One Girl Save Humanity? | Season 1 | THE PASSAGE" on YouTube, android.intent.extra.TEXT=https://youtu.be/5TkqFuiHwFg}]}
```

So you need the `android.intent.extra.SUBJECT` key and the `android.intent.extra.TEXT`, but those are native Android keys. You will want to use the Xamarin.Android equivalents, which are `Intent.ExtraSubject` and `Intent.ExtraText`

So in the `OnCreate` method in the Activity that is handling the `Intent`, all you should have to do is:

```
var bundle = Intent.Extras;
var url = bundle?.GetString(Intent.ExtraText);
var subject = bundle?.GetString(Intent.ExtraSubject);
```

Note the null checks on bundle as bundle will be null when the app first launches and will only be non-null when sharing a video from Youtube.